# Does RapidXML support xml:space="preserve"?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, rapidxml

I'm reading an XML file where I have "whitespace-only text nodes":

```
<p>I <b>love</b> <i>Mozart</i>.</p>
```

In the above (simplified) example, there is whitespace (a single space) between the  end tag and the  start tag.  I need to preserve that space.

When parsing in RapidXML, I am ONLY specifying "parse_comment_nodes", so I assume "parse_trim_whitespace" and "parse_normalize_whitespace" are NOT in effect.  So I'm attempting to use the "xml:space" syntax:

```
<p xml:space="preserve">I <b>love</b> <i>Mozart</i>.</p>
```

...but it seems as if RapidXML doesn't respect that.  As I loop through all the sibling nodes, I never see a node with a value of " ".

I've been reading (and re-reading) the documentation, and searching here on StackOverflow, but so far haven't figured out if this is a syntax issue on my part, or a RapidXML issue.

Comment: After searching in the RapidXML sources, I can't find any reference to either "XML:space" or "preserve" -- I think it's unlikely this feature is supported by RapidXML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I'm POSITIVE that RapidXML 1.13 doesn't support working around whitespace-only text nodes using the xml:space="preserve" attribute.  I located a PATCH for this very issue on SourceForge:

[Link to patch for RapidXML 1.13 whitespace-only text node bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/rapidxml/patches/4/)

This patch corrects the problem of RapidXML simply never returning/skipping a valid node when it only contained whitespace.  It DOES NOT enable use of the xml:space="preserve" attribute.  That would be the preferable method of ENABLING the bugfix.  Perhaps someone more familiar with the RapidXML project can make that change in the future.